# firestore document modification history best practices

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

What is the best solution for keeping track of document modifications in firestore?
#askfirebase

**version a:** onUpdate cloud function that stores the modifications inside the same document inside a map field.
This will trigger a second onUpdate and if the modified field is the history attribute we exit without any modification and prevent infinite loop.

This will also trigger two more reads on that document.

in total 2 writes and 2 or 2 reads
on the long term the document will need only one read to show the complete info

**version b:** create a separate collection (CollectionA_History) and store modifications in a document with the same ID
this will trigger two writes but on the long term whenever you need the history of that document you trigger a second read

the plan is to store the modifications in the following format

```
[{
  when: timeStamp,
  who: uid,
  what: [{
    field: 'attributes.color',
    oldValue: 'red',
    newValue: 'yellow'
  }]
},
{
  when: timeStamp,
  who: uid,
  what: [{
    field: 'attributes.size',
    oldValue: 'xl',
    newValue: 'xxl'
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no singular "best" here as it all depends on your needs, preferences and tolerances of the project. But I'd typically store the document history in a `history` subcollection under each document itself. Doing this in Cloud Functions is indeed a great option.